# A command is needed for listing the upgradable snap packages under ubuntu-22.04

Tags: apt, snap, partial-upgrade

command for listing the upgradable snap packages, similiarly to command

> sudo apt list upgradable

as  "sudo snap refresh" is also missing a --test flag.

Comment: Not Sure `snap refresh --list` i have no snap

Answer (score 0):

```
snap refresh --list
```

Sudo is not required, as you are not installing nor removing software.

Snap-provided applications that are not running will update automatically, so you are unlikely to see those listed.

Snap-provided applications that are currently running (like Firefox) will show up on the list. These are the same applications that will send you a 14-day countdown notification, so you can also accomplish the same check by looking at your old notifications (Gnome: Click on the date at the top of the screen).